# How can I use a ref to change class name of the element I have clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, getelementbyid, ref

I want to make refs that reference each cell in the graph. Doing the usual way, I only get the reference to the last cell created in the graph.
I have the details below:

How I am generating the grid:

```
class Grid {
  getInitialGrid() {
    const grid = [];
    for (let row = 0; row < row_size; row++) {
      const currentRow = [];
      for (let col = 0; col < col_size; col++) {
        currentRow.push(this.createNode(col, row));
      }
      grid.push(currentRow);
    }
    return grid;
  };



  createNode(col, row) {
    return {
      col,
      row,
    };
  };
}
```

The .jsx file that I have. I have indicated the place where the ref should be

```
        <div
          className="table"

        >
          {grid.map((row, index) => {
            return (
              <div key={index}
              >
                {row.map((node) => {
                  
                  
                  return ( // each node
                    <div key={col}
                      //this is where I want to use the ref
                      id={`${row}-${col}`}
                      className={`cell ${this.classNameFunc(begNode, endNode, wallNode, isVisited)}`}
                      onMouseDown={() => this.mouseTest(row, col)}
                    >
                    </div>
                  );
                })}
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
```

Comment: You do not need ref to change the class on the element you click on. Simpler to use onClick event and handle a class of the element (add/remove) in an assigned callback.

Comment: please come with a working snippet, if you have a snippet that shows your problem clearly, it will solve your problem much faster compare to come without a snippet, in example, you can create a snippet from code sandbox

Comment: There's not enough code here to debug your issue. Also, you should only be using refs as a last-resort; they're an escape hatch from the React world. Why do you want to use refs?

Comment: @DavidFrederick Sir, I am using refs to change class name of some cells in my graph.
To everyone else, thank you for the feedback, I will improve my question next time.

Comment: @IsaKurbanov why not use CSS modules (which come with create-react-app) and just assign a className? You don't need refs for css modules and classnames to work.